# Google sheets script moving cells at the end of the line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I want to create a macro in order to move cells at the end of a line, in a empty cell. Giving that all my lines have different lengths... The idea is to archive tasks already done, moving them at the end.
I'm a beginner, so i tried this script but it doesn't work. The cells don't move to the right places :

```html
function Taskdone() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var lastColumn = cell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
  var newCell = cell.offset(0,lastColumn);
  var rowcell = cell.getRow();
  var columncell = cell.getColumn();
  var rownewCell = newCell.getRow();
  var columnnewCell = newCell.getColumn();
  sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#d9d9d9');
  sheet.getRange(rowcell,columncell).moveTo(sheet.getRange(rownewCell,columnnewCell));
};
```

Can you tell me where I was wrong ?
Thanks for your advices and sorry for my english. This is not my native language...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved :

```html
function Taskdone() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var rowcell = cell.getRow();
  var columncell = cell.getColumn();
  var columnnewCell = cell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground('#d9d9d9');
sheet.getRange(rowcell,columncell).moveTo(sheet.getRange(rowcell,columnnewCell+1));
};
```